# Get the build number in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    tag: ''
    packVersionSuffix: ''
    # versionSuffix seems to be a special magic name, so setting it makes stuff break.
    
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
    tag: ${{ format('-{0}.{1}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['Build.BuildId']) }}
    packVersionSuffix: ${{ format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['Build.BuildId'], 'two' ) }}

steps:

- script: echo "packVersionSuffix is $(packVersionSuffix)"
```

After substituting in the `{1}` but is always the empty string, i.e. the value of `variables['Build.BuildId']` is always the empty string.

How can I get the actual build number instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit afraid that you won't be able to get `BuildId` here as this is not available in expressions:

[image]

So you need to build your `packVersionSuffix` in powershell step and then assign it to Azure Devops variable via logging command.

Answer (score 0):

As is typical with Azure pipelines: it just doesn't work.

Here is something...

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set versionSuffix (when not master)'
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
         $packVersionSuffix = "$(Build.SourceBranchName).$(Build.BuildId)"
         echo "packVersionSuffix is: ${packVersionSuffix}"
         # This sets the variable in the whole pipeline
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packVersionSuffix]$packVersionSuffix"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set versionSuffix (when master)'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
          $packVersionSuffix = ""
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packVersionSuffix]$packVersionSuffix"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack Project'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'Folder\Project.csproj'
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    nobuild: true
    buildProperties: 'VersionSuffix="$(packVersionSuffix)"'
    versionSuffix: '$(packVersionSuffix'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    arguments: '--version-suffix $(packVersionSuffix)'
```

Comment: Hi @RichardBarraclough, thanks a lot for sharing your experiences. I recommend that you can mark your answer as the solution of this topic. This may be also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.